# Unity WebGL Dev-Build: Automatically save profiling data (to filesystem)

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, profiler

The issue is that I want to automate profiling and saving profiling data of my WebGL project during the 'Build & Run' of a Developmentbuild. However, to my knowledge, in this way the script does not have direct access to the local file system, as the content is run in a browser. If profiling is enabled and saved through script, it will end up in the IndexedDB. I don't have the knowledge to automatically extract and save this data from the IndexedDB to my filesystem.

If the profiling has to be done manualy it will be an enormous time-sink. Is there a workaround to automatically save profiling data from a WebGL development-build to your filesystem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could have a local HTTP file server running (I once wrote a pretty simple one in Java for research purpose - can't find in anymore unfortunately ^^ .. ASP.NET would also do if you are more familiar with c# anyway) and then use `UnityWebRequest` in order to send files to that http server

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server